# How can I implement matlabs ``ismember()`` command in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

here is my problem: I would like to create a boolean matrix B that contains `True` everywhere that matrix A has a value contained in vector v. One inconvenient solution would be:

```
import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
>>> v = [1,2]
>>> B = (A==v[0]) + (A==v[1]) # matlab: ``B = ismember(A,v)``
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Is there maybe a solution that would be more convenient if A and v would have more values?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much numpy, be here's a raw python one:

```
>>> A = [[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
>>> v = [1,2]
>>> B = [map(lambda val: val in v, a) for a in A]
>>>
>>> B
[[False, True, True], [True, True, False], [True, False, False]]
```

**Edit**: As Brooks Moses notes and some simple timing seems to show, this one is probably be better:

```
>>> B = [ [val in v for val in a] for a in A]
```

Comment: Naive question: Why the map(lambda...) syntax, rather than just [(val in v) for v in a]?  Is there a meaningful difference in this case?

Comment: @Brooks Moses: You're right, I guess there's not, and the double comprehension even seems to be a little faster (I only did some naive timing, though). Edited.

Comment: Actually, for small v and large A, it's a lot faster (factor 2).

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy primitives:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
>>> v = [1,2]
>>> print np.vectorize(lambda x: x in v)(A)
[[False  True  True]
 [ True  True False]
 [ True False False]]
```

For non-tiny inputs convert v to a set first for a large speedup.

To use numpy.setmember1d:

```
Auniq, Ainv = np.unique1d(A, return_inverse=True)
result = np.take(np.setmember1d(Auniq, np.unique1d(v)), Ainv).reshape(A.shape)
```

Comment: This is broken: see the 2nd row, rightmost column -- what's that True doing there?  It corresponds to 3 in A which is NOT in v. Alas, setmember1d does NOT support correctly arrays with duplicates.

Comment: Corrected, setmember1d documentation could be clearer on this.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, `setmember1d` as it exists in numpy is broken when either array has duplicated elements (as A does here).  Download [this](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/raw-attachment/ticket/872/setmember.py) version, call it e.g sem.py somewhere on your sys.path, add to it a first line `import numpy as nm`, and THEN this finally works:

```
>>> import sem
>>> print sem.setmember1d(A.reshape(A.size), v).reshape(A.shape)
[[False True True]
 [True True False]
 [True False False]]
```

Note the difference wrt @Aants' similar answer: this version has the second row of the resulting bool array correct, while his version (using the `setmember1d` that comes as part of numpy) incorrectly has the second row as all `True`s.

Answer (score 2):

Since Numpy version 1.4 there's a new function, in1d() that's the equivalent of ismember() in matlab: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html. But as ars points out, it only returns a 1d array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive one-liner:

```
[any (value in item for value in v) for item in A]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> A = ( [0,1,2], [1,2,3], [2,3,4] )
>>> v = [1,2]
>>> [any (value in item for value in v) for item in A]
[True, True, True]
>>> v = [1]
>>> [any (value in item for value in v) for item in A]
[True, True, False]
```

It's a very Pythonic approach, but I'm certain it won't scale well on large arrays or vectors because Python's `in` operator is a linear search (on lists/tuples, at least).

As Brooks Moses pointed out in the below comment, the output should be a 3x3 matrix.  That's why you give sample output in your questions.  (Thanks Brooks)

```
>>> v=[1,2]
>>> [ [item in v for item in row] for row in A]
[[False, True, True], [True, True, False], [True, False, False]]
>>> v=[1]
>>> [ [item in v for item in row] for row in A]
[[False, True, False], [True, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

Comment: You've got a good answer to the wrong question, I think -- you want A to be a 3x3 array, and return a 3x3 truth value for each of those 9 elements.  Thus, adjusting your answer slightly: [[(item in v) for item in row] for row in A] works fine.  I'm also curious why you expect this would be slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you'll get is `numpy.ismember1d`, but it won't work well with your example.  I think your solution (`B = (A==v[0]) + (A==v[1])`) may actually be the best one.